# Sending data from sleeping Xbee module

Tags: arduino, xbee

I am using XBee series 2 module for communication between arduino and computer. I have coordinator attached with computer and an end device with arduino. I want to send data from arduino after every 1 min. But the problem is i am using cyclic sleep mode on end device with ST (time before sleep = 5 sec which is default value). I first send data as soon as module is on which works fine.But then after 5 sec module enters in sleep mode. Then after 1 min i am unable to send data to computer. In fact my end device module does not communicate with arduino either. Any idea how to awake sleeping module?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at pin 9, the "sleep request" pin.  I believe the host can use that pin to wake a sleeping XBee, or tell it that it's OK to go to sleep.

I found a blog post on "[Low-Power XBee Sleep Mode with Arduino and Pin Hibernation](http://www.fiz-ix.com/2012/11/low-power-xbee-sleep-mode-with-arduino-and-pin-hibernation/)" that should get you pointed in the right direction.